# In the Movie Dragon Ball Z Resurrection of F Why did Shen-long grant them two wishes while in Battle of the Gods granted them only one?

Tags: dragon-ball-z

In the Movie Dragon Ball Z Resurrection of F Why did Shen-long grant them two wishes even though in the previous movie granted them only one?

I remember Dende upgrading ShenLong to grant two wishes but in Battle of the Gods he granted one and in Resurrection of F he granted two. Why is that? What is the current status of Shen Long's wish granting power?

Comment: Because dende upgraded him at some point.

Comment: When was that? I mean from the fight with Beerus up to the ressurection of Frieza we have nothing of that

Comment: @JohnDemetriou It was near the end of DBZ.  They needed a new Guardian after Kami and Piccolo fused, so Goku recruits Dende who then proceeds to refashion the dragon.

Comment: I remember that part, what I do not understand is why in Battle of the Gods Shenlong was granting one wish and in the next movie he was granting two wishes

Comment: @AnkitSharma Little Green could do that?

Comment: Pure speculation but after the dragon balls were upgraded to allow two wishes, it was revealed that both do not have to be made right away. You could use one wish and dismiss the dragon, resulting in the Dragon Balls only becoming inert for four months instead of a year. The next time the dragon was summoned, however, he would only grant the one remaining wish. It's possible that in Battle of Gods, a single wish had been made four months prior and they only had one remaining.

Comment: @aleppke Thanks. That more or less explains it yes

Comment: Upvoted to counter the downvote as the question is on topic and is a good question. I'll answer soon if alepkke doesn't post. I want to watch the scene again to answer more accurately :)

Comment: @CandiedMango I really wondered why the downvote to be hones, and with no comment accompanying it

Comment: I guess your question could appear unclear to some. The comments haven't helped for clarity as they are talking about things that happened way before battle of gods.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

During the Battle of the Gods movie Shenron is summoned in order to answer Gokus question about the Super Saiyan God. However upon seeing Lord Beerus Shenron becomes noticeably flustered, Beerus commands Shenron to answer the question about the Super Saiyan God when Shenron completes his take he seemingly runs away with his tail between his legs.
 [See the scene here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IZ7M0so7hEM)

During the Cell saga (before he becomes perfect) Kame and Piccolo join once more, when this happens the Dragonballs cease to exist in their current form as there is no current guardian of Earth.

Goku then teleports to the new planet Namek and retrieves Dende who with the help of Mr Popo reforges the Dragonballs and the Dragon giving the Dragonballs new powers most noticeably from 1 wish to 2 wishes.

**Terminology**

When Dende remakes the Dragonballs he says that Shenron can now grant 3 wishes, Piccolo asks if Shenron can still bring back a large number of people to which Dende answers okay but if that happens then you only get 2 wishes.

This can be taken as Shenron can only ever grant 2 wishes because he is capable of this power or Shenron can only grant 2 wishes if one of those wishes is bring back a large group of people.

Now in the battle of gods and resurrection F movies we see 3 wishes granted.

1. Gokus information about SSGod
2. Frieza to be revived
3. A million zeni for Shuu

Considering none of these are large scale revives this could be a set of 3 wishes. Where Shenron fled after the first wish. Normally when this happens the Dragonballs have a smaller cooling off period I.E 6months instead of a year (This would however only grant the remaining wishes)

**Clarification**

Based on what I have read it doesn't seem to matter how much longer you wait after the Dragonballs are used. So the gap between the wishes of Battle of Gods and Ressurection F of 6 months (thereabouts) doesn't matter as once a wish is granted and Shenron is sent away he can only grant the remaining wishes when he is next summoned.

Presumably this doesn't happen if the balls are left for a year which would begin the cycle a new.

Comment: So more or less it could be possible that Resurrection of F happened barely 6 months after Kami vs Kami? Or to state it better, the dragonballs cooled off 6 months after Kami vs Kami isntead of a full year?

Comment: I'm pretty confident that Revival of F happens about 6 months after Battle of Gods anyway.. Doesn't Goku make a comment about it?

Comment: @stormie yeah I think you're right. Another explanation is that just before the events of BoG emperor pilaf and his crew ask the dragon for eternal youth ( I'm unaware how long before ) I'll edit my answer tomorrow. (In about 10 hours)

Comment: This is a better answer than I would have given. I didn't know Shenron could do three wishes. I knew Dende wanted to make him that way but I interpreted the scene as him being unable to maintain the three wishes if Shenron was to be powerful enough to revive many people at once. After reading the Dragonball wikia, I see that he can indeed grant three wishes if none of them involve mass revivals.

Comment: btw after your response it helped revert the negative votes of my question :D

Comment: @JohnDemetriou I'm glad you found the answer you were looking for! I'm always around to answer DB/DBZ questions.